# How to get the positions where a sequence was aligned as output of a pair-wise alignment?

Tags: python, r, bioinformatics

So I have a reference DNA sequence, and I have many query sequences. I want to do a pair-wise alignment of every query sequence, one at a time, to the reference sequence.

And I am looking for the best way to get, as output, the starting and ending positions (of the reference sequence) of where the alignment was done.

I have tried using some R functions to do the pair-wise alignment, but I haven't found any that tells me the alignment positions in relation to the reference DNA sequence.

Does anyone know a good way to do this with R or python?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Please give a reproducible example with sample (mock-up) data that suits your problem and also share the code that you have tried so far.

Comment: This type of domain-specific question is better suited to https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/ and may be closed here for being [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

Use Bioconductor's [Biostrings](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/Biostrings.html) for this. The package provides means for comparing DNA strings (eg. using the `matchPattern()` function.

A simple example:

```
library(Biostrings)
reference <- DNAString("ACTGACTGACTG")
query <- DNAStringSet(c("TG", "TGAC", "TGACTG"))
lapply(query, matchPattern, reference)
```

In this case, `matchPattern()` will provide you the start/end positions and match width in `reference` where each of the query sequences are found.

```
[[1]]
Views on a 12-letter DNAString subject
subject: ACTGACTGACTG
views:
      start end width
  [1]     3   4     2 [TG]
  [2]     7   8     2 [TG]
  [3]    11  12     2 [TG]

[[2]]
Views on a 12-letter DNAString subject
subject: ACTGACTGACTG
views:
      start end width
  [1]     3   6     4 [TGAC]
  [2]     7  10     4 [TGAC]

[[3]]
Views on a 12-letter DNAString subject
subject: ACTGACTGACTG
views:
      start end width
  [1]     3   8     6 [TGACTG]
  [2]     7  12     6 [TGACTG]
```